# What makes this simple recursion not work?

Tags: javascript, recursion

the First one doesn't work, its just trying to find a factorial, it returns NaN, so why is it if you use else if it doesnt work?

```
function FirstFactorial(num) {
  if (num == 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  else if (num > 1) {
    return num * FirstFactorial(num - 1);
  }
}


console.log(FirstFactorial(3)) === NaN



function factorial(n) {
  if(n == 0) {
    return 1
  } 
  else {
    return n * factorial(n - 1);
  }
}

console.log(factorial(3)) == 6
```

Comment: `console.log(FirstFactorial(3)) === NaN` does not make sense. Do you mean the console displays `NaN` ?

Comment: Watch out for a stack overflow if they pass a negative number into the function :)

Comment: I think maybe you meant to do `else if (num >= 1)` instead of only doing greater than 1.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a case for `num === 1`, so when you do

```
function FirstFactorial(num) {
  if (num == 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  else if (num > 1) {
    return num * FirstFactorial(num - 1);
  }
}

FirstFactorial(3);
```

You're doing

```
3 * FirstFactorial(2);
3 * 2 * FirstFactorial(1);
3 * 2 * undefined; // NaN
```

Re-arrange the function logic thus

```
function FirstFactorial(num) {
    if (num > 1) {
        return num * FirstFactorial(num - 1);
    }
    return 1;
}
```